# Different types of user sessions in CakePHP

Tags: session, authentication, cakephp

I'm developing an app with CakePHP and in my app I have an admin section that us under Cake's Auth and it's associated, and I also have my frontend that should have another Auth session for regular users, how can I manage this? Or would I have to make my own registering and login methods for my regular users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth using CakePHP's ACL component - you can specify permissions quite easily on which user/group can access which controller/action.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

Comment: I already have my admin users under ACL and I don't want the regular users and the admin users in the same database table

Comment: Make another table for your regular users and setup the relationship accordingly:

User hasOne Profile.
Check http://book.cakephp.org/view/1041/hasOne